# Цикл While php добавить символы в начало переменной

Tags: php, while, for

помогите решить задачу на php
Есть переменная с значением 456

Нужно ее проверить и если количество символов в ней меньше 6 , то добавить в начало нули

Должно получится 000456

Comment: `$str = strlen($str) < 6 ? str_repeat('0', strlen($str)) . $str : $str;`

Answer (score 3):

Зачем проверять?

```
echo sprintf("%06d", 456);
```

Comment: я что-то вспоминал-вспоминал как `format` в пхп выглядит, так и не вспомнил :D

Comment: @teran суровые разработчики даже не гуглят? Но ведь память имеет свойство подводить))

Comment: такие вещи обычно не забывают :)

Answer (score 2):

например,  так

```
echo  str_pad($val, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

но если задача именно в `while`, то

```
while(strlen($v) < 6) $v = " $v";
```

Comment: С каждым ответом строка кода всё меньше и меньше, боюсь что будет дальше xd

Comment: Дальше вообще вот так: `while(strlen($v = '0' . $v) < 6);`

Answer (score 0):

Решение по быстрому:

```
$num = 456;

for($i = 0; strlen($num) < 6; $i++){
    $num = 0 . $num;
}

var_dump($num);
```

Вывод:

```
 string(6) "000456"
```